# Debuging in Release mode MSVS after disabling optimization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I had to debug a problem in C++ code using MSVS. However, the `Debug` mode was not configured well in the `Debug` mode (linking has not been done). So, I had to do the work in the `Release` mode. In order to get the correct values of all variables and not skipping any line, I just disabled all compiler Optimization and every thing went well with me. Is it really enough to stop optimization in order to debug any code? In other words, what does `Debug` mode provide more than that?

**Edit:** The things that the programmer or the standered library implemnter added to the code under an `#ifdef DEBUG` does not count in my question. I just want to know about the thing that the compiler/IDE provides.

Comment: Use DEBUG configuration to debug code except when you cannot reproduce the problem in DEBUG version.

Comment: Debugging a Release-built program is quite possible.  Except that the debugger gets wonky, it sometimes can't display a value of a local variable, single-stepping acts weird, breakpoints end up in the wrong location.  By disabling the optimizer the debugger no longer acts wonky.  You won't get the benefit of other Debug settings, /RTC is the big one and Edit+Continue won't work.  You can get them to work by changing settings.  Eventually you'll end up with a build that's indistinguishable from a Debug build :)

Comment: @HansPassant I see. Thanks :)